# Saving special characters in Approval Comment

Tags: apex

The Salesforce Approval Comment is limited to 4000 characters. I have a visualforce page which saves the text of a textarea in an approval process comment. I limited the textarea so that the user can enter only 4000 characters.

The problem rises when I enter special characters like french accents which takes up more than 4000 characters when saved in Salesforce. I am receiving the error 'Invalid character encoding' which we believe rises when the french text is truncated to be saved in the approval comment section. 
The same error will rise when saving other language like chinese or german, etc.

Anyone dealt with this before ? Any solution to this?

Thanks
Nawshine